# Create dictionary in swift with array of strings as value

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

When creating a dictionary in swift with array of strings as value as follows:

```
lazy var info : Dictionary = {

    var dictionary = [String: [String]]()
    dictionary["Key1"] = ["A", "B", "C"]
    dictionary["Key2"] = ["D", "E", "F"]

    return dictionary  
}()
```

Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Value?'

Any ideas whats wrong here?

Comment: This error message usually comes up, when declaring dictionary with `let`. But you have done it right in this snippet. Are you sure, you've done it the same way in your real code?

Comment: The problem was that you can't use Dictionary with a lazy var - had to change Dictionary to NSDictionary and all was fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen your own answer, which works, but there's a better way: use a Swift dictionary by declaring its proper type, in your case `[String: [String]]`:

```
lazy var info : [String: [String]] = {

    var dictionary = [String: [String]]()
    dictionary["Key1"] = ["A", "B", "C"]
    dictionary["Key2"] = ["D", "E", "F"]

    return dictionary
}()
```

Comment: Was just going to comment this too. @XCodeWarrier It is even better to keep all type declarations separate from initial values `var dictionary : [String: [String]] = [:]`

Comment: Perfect answer! Let's keep moving forward with Swift instead of resorting to the old Objective-C classes (like `NSDictionary`).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
lazy var info : Dictionary = {

    var dictionary = [String: [String]]()
    dictionary["Key1"] = ["A", "B", "C"]
    dictionary["Key2"] = ["D", "E", "F"]

    return dictionary  
}()
```

to

```
lazy var info : NSDictionary = {

    var dictionary = [String: [String]]()
    dictionary["Key1"] = ["A", "B", "C"]
    dictionary["Key2"] = ["D", "E", "F"]

    return dictionary  
}()
```

and all is good :)